# What function would っての have in these contexts?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

> 1. 亜衣麻衣美衣が壁を作るようにして、士道の進路を阻んでくる。 「ちょっと待てゴルァァァァァ！」 「乙女を辱めておいてどこに行こう**っての**よ！」「現行犯よ！逃がさないんだから！」

> 2. 「馬鹿にすんじゃないわよ！ジェットコースターの制限って一一〇センチとかじゃない！さすがにそんなに小さくない**っての**！」
>    (the sister wanted to ride the roller coaster but the brother was afraid she was too short)

Do the two bold ってのs have the same function? If they do, what would the function be? It seems these ってのs are not equivalent to というのか.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

っての is not short for というのか but short for というの or といっているの. ("っての?" can still be a question with a rising intonation.)

The first ての (=というの) is used to seeking clarification. The second ての is just "I say", and it's a way of emphasizing something with an irritated overtone.

Related:

- [Meaning of ってのも/というのも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38822/5010)
- [How would one parse "金ってのは金のある[…]"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51934/5010)

Comment: Thank you. So does the first ってのよ imply that the listener was told not to go anywhere? (Like a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @chinoalpha Yes, literally something like "Where are you saying you're going to?", but "Where are you going to?" or "Do you think you can get out of here?" works.